# Does curl -Ls 'http://example.com' mean it will not output anything?

Tags: linux, command-line, command, cd-command, command-substitution

Does the `s` in `-Ls` mean that nothing should be outputted?

If so what will be the output then?

Comment: I just have to note that I'm incredibly surprised by what happened when I went to that URL. Not what I expected at all!

Answer (score 1):

No, here is the output:

```
curl -Ls 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=r2jYDZaw'
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            jQuery('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jQuery('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    jQuery('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

});%
```

from man page:

```
-s, --silent
              Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output  the  data  you
              ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.
```

Comment: Thanks, but the http://ss64.com/osx/ls.html says the s will make the output silent

Comment: @RickAstley But `curl` is not `ls`, even if the sequence `Ls` appears in the curl options.

Comment: so what will be the output if we did curl -Ls 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=r2jYDZaw' | sort | head output. Thanks

Comment: `curl -Ls 'pastebin.com/raw.php?i=r2jYDZaw' | sort | head `  returns  
`});
 });
 });
  }
 
 
 
 //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
 //Click event to scroll to top
  } else {
`

Comment: @RickAstley What are you trying to accomplish here? That's not a thing which really makes sense to sort.

Comment: Im just learning how to use the curl command really, Thanks for the help everyone